# Enable Facebook Like Button in Game Center

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, game-center, facebook-ios-sdk

When opening Game Center in my iOS app, I see a Facebook like button which is grayed out. Beneath the button is the text: "Facebook Liking Unavailable". My question is: how do I enable Facebook liking, and how do I specify which page will get the like? Do I have to put my app's Facebook URL into the code somewhere?

Comment: When in sandbox mode the Facebook like button in Game Center is automatically disabled. Upon release to the App Store the button is enabled. There is nothing you need to do for this to happen. The like button is setup to like your app. You can try this yourself on any Game Center enabled app by tapping the like button, then going to Facebook.com and checking your activity feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your settings in `Settings` | `Facebook` current so that you are authenticated? FWIK that should be all there is to it.

Comment: Yes, those settings are current so that I am authenticated. How does the Game Center Facebook Like system work? If someone taps the like button, are they liking my Facebook page? If so, how does Game Center know which page is mine? I am still testing the app/it is in sandbox if that makes any difference.

Comment: @StephenVondenstein It's for "liking" your app. A user must be authenticated to 1) Game Center and 2) Facebook.